# How to configure Eclipse to format all java code except Strings declaration?

Tags: java, eclipse

How to configure Eclipse to format all java code **except** Strings declaration?

Example:

Before Ctrl+I:

```
    String sql = 
        "Select column " + 
        "from   table  " +
        " where column1 > 0 AND column2 < 0";
```

After Ctrl+I:

```
    String sql = "Select column " + "from   table  "
            + " where column1 > 0 AND column2 < 0";
```

Thank you!

**edit:**

Has any way to configure using Formatter preferences (Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the `@formatter:on` and `@formatter:off` tags in the formatter preferences:

```
// @formatter:off
String s = "..." + 
           "..." ...
// @formatter:on
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `//` to prevent the formatting like this:

```
String sql = //
        "Select column " + //
        "from   table  " + //
        " where column1 > 0 AND column2 < 0";
```

That's not very nice but works in every case (i.e. when your coworkers don't use *exactly* the same settings in Eclipse).

Comment: That's what I do for enums as well. +1 for the point about coworkers.